# htaccess hide file name from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to hide the `profile.php` from appearing in the URL.
So here's what I have:

The URL I am accessing:

```
sampleuser.domain.com/profile.php
```

How I get the user 'sampleuser':

```
$url = "//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

/*this will give me $url = '//sampleuser.domain.com/profile.php'; */

function get_user_from_url($url)
{
    if (strpos($url , 'www.') !== false) {
        preg_match('/\/\/www.(.*?)\.domain/', $url, $val);
    }
    else
    {
        preg_match('/\/\/(.*?)\./', $url, $val);
    }
    return $val[1];
}

$user = get_user_from_url($url);
echo $user;
```

I just need to hide the `profile.php`, also the thing to consider is if we hide the `profile.php`, it might conflict with the index.php.

But luckily we will only access the index.php if the URL is only domain.com (without user).

I'm low on `htaccess` knowledge, can anyone give me the direct answer, and I would be very appreciative if you can add some explanation, it'll give me a head start on learning `htaccess`.

Comment: Why not just rename `profile.php` to `index.php` and check if the domain is `domain.com` or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, what I was making is a dynamic subdomain. So I added a subdomain on my DNS:
     *.domain.com

then added these on my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /agent/index.php?user=%2 [L]
</IfModule>
```